# Mathematical representation for a diagonal matrix with special property

Tags: matrices, notation

$A\in {\mathbb{C}}^{N\times N}$ is a diagonal matrix, $\textbf{A}=\text{diag}(a_1,...,a_{N})$ and $g=N/K$. So I can group diagonal entries in to $g$ groups, each having $K$ entries. Each group has only one non-zero entry, let us say 1. E.g., if $N=9$ and $K=3$, then, $g=3$. So I may have $\textbf{A}=\text{diag}(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0)$ in which there are three groups and each group has one non-zero element.

I want to define this in more general way with correct mathematical notations.  Can someone please help me?